# How to automatically give dot2tex edges a style depending on their endpoints?

Tags: tikz-pgf, dot2tex, dot2texi

I need to typeset graphs but I do not want to place the nodes by hand. I use the `dot2texi` package to automatically translate graph descriptions into tikz/pgf commands. This works great.

I also want to create `beamer` slides to illustrate the action of graph algorithms (DFS, Prim, etc.). I thus need to highlight nodes, which I do by drawing colored nodes on a background layer at the same positions as the nodes generated by dot2texi. This also works.

I need to highlight edges too. [My source for highlighting nodes](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/prims-algorithm/) does edges in the same manner: they are redrawn thanks to knowing their endpoints. This works there because the edges are straight.

In my case, edges are bent in a manner I do not know (and do not want to know), so knowing both endpoints is not sufficient.

It is possible to reuse a path for a second drawing thanks to [this SX question & answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26382/calling-a-previously-named-path-in-tikz). I tried and this also works.

But this requires to give the paths a name (in contrast to nodes which are referencable in their own right) during their creation, which in my case is automated.

Currently, I am cheating with the `style` feature of the dot language: it happens to put the text I need at the right place in the generated tikz commands when run through dot2texi.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \tikzstyle{basevertex} = [circle,
  inner sep=0pt,
  minimum size=.5cm,
  font=\scriptsize]

 \tikzstyle{vertex} = [basevertex, draw]

 \tikzstyle{dotvertex} = [vertex]
\tikzstyle{selected edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,red!50]

%% here follows the code from [2]
%%% etc.
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{dot2texi}[codeonly, styleonly, tikz]
         graph G {
            rankdir="LR";
            node[style="dotvertex", fontsize=8];
            0 -- 1 -- 3;
            0 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4;
            3 -- 7;
            2 -- 6;
            5 -- 2;
            5 -- 4 [style="name path global=test"];
           }
       \end{dot2texi}
       \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
          \path[use path=test, selected edge];
       \end{pgfonlayer}
     \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

gives, as intended,

[image: result from above code]

I am now trying to automate the naming/styling of path according to their endpoints (I will not typeset multigraphs), like `edge(origin)(destination)` so that I can refer them without bothering to manually name them in my dot code.