# Draw a previously named path in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a previously named path in TikZ?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \path[name path=mypath] (0,0) -- (5,5);
    
    %\draw[use path=mypath]; % This does not work
    
    %\path[mypath, draw]; % This does not work

\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

The answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26386/96172) has a macro for `use path` option. Is there a solution within TikZ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is just wrong syntax. After you name a path via `[save path]`, you can recall it with `[use path]`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[save path=\mypath] (0,0) -- (5,5);
\draw[use path=\mypath]; % This works now
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

The key `[name path]` of the library `intersections` has totally different use. The keys `[name path]` and `[save path]` can be combined. See Section 14.22 in [pgfmanual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for more details.

[image]