# Cannot decorate an empty path

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths, decorations

I want to save a path, draw it cropped and put an arrow on it

```
\documentclass[10pt,convert={convertexe=magick,density=1000,outext=.png}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path[save path=\test] (0,0) -- (5,5);
\node at (0,0) {origin};

\begin{scope}
\clip (1,1) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}][use path=\test];
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Well, putting arrow does not work, because I get the message

```
! Package pgf Error: I cannot decorate an empty path.
```

What is a workaround for this problem?

Comment: A quick fix would probably be to use `\newcommand{\test}{ (0,0) -- (5,5) }` instead of saving the path. I also found these answers that might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127045/47927 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26386/47927

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `use path` facility provided by TikZ is not quite as sophisticated as it needs to be.  In particular, it doesn't make the path work with actions and decorations.

My [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) library (development version on [`github`](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3)) handles this correctly, as in the following version of your code.

Note that if you want your line drawn *and* decorated then you should put the decoration in a pre or post action.

```
\documentclass[10pt,convert={convertexe=magick,density=1000,outext=.png}]{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650655/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,spath3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path[spath/save=test] (0,0) -- (5,5);
\node at (0,0) {origin};

\begin{scope}
\clip (1,1) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}][spath/use=test];
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: decorated re-used path]

Comment: OK, I just realised that this does not work in the my actual situation, which is saving paths with `\addplot` in `axis` environment.  The original question was meant to be a simplification of the problem, perhaps I oversimplified.  Is there a workaround for that too?

Comment: I opened a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650703/cannot-decorate-an-empty-path-in-pgfplot