# Cannot decorate an empty path in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, paths, decorations

I want to save a plot, draw it cropped and put an arrow on it

```
\documentclass[10pt,convert={convertexe=magick,density=1000,outext=.png}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
\addplot[save path=\test] coordinates {(0,0) (2,3) (5,5)};

\begin{scope}
\clip (axis cs:1,1) rectangle (axis cs:4,4);
% \draw[red][use path=\test];  % <-- THIS WORKS
\draw[red,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}][use path=\test];
\end{scope}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Well, putting arrow does not work, because I get the message

```
! Package pgf Error: I cannot decorate an empty path.
```

What is a workaround for this problem?

The solution provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650655/cannot-decorate-an-empty-path) does not work

[image]

Comment: `addplot` introduces lots of scopes and groupings. Does the code from the other answer work if you use `spath/save global` instead?

Comment: @AndrewStacey `I do not know the key '\pgfplots\spath\save`, the same for `save global`

Comment: That's about relative versus absolute paths in pgfkeys.  Try `/tikz/spath/save global`

Comment: @AndrewStacey `/tikz/spath/save global` works, great!  Will you provide the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing `pgfplots` and `tikz` has a few unforeseen hitches that can catch out the unwary.

The first is that `\addplot` doesn't render its path at the invocation time but rather it gets saved up for the end of the `axis` environment.  So a path defined by `\addplot` is not available until after the `axis` environment ends.  Fortunately, a `pgfplots` axis also affects normal TikZ `\draw` (and similar) commands so these also get gathered up and dealt with at the end of the `axis` environment.  So you don't notice this in your situation, but it is worth knowing about.

The second is that `\addplot` also introduces lots of scopes, which introduce TeX groups, and so things that are defined locally don't last out of their groups.  So the `spath/save` from the previous answer needs to be replaced by `spath/save global` to make the path global.

The third is that `\addplot` takes its key values by default in the `pgfplots` directory.  So the `spath` key needs to have its absolute path and be invoked as `/tikz/spath/save global`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,convert={convertexe=magick,density=1000,outext=.png}]{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650703/86}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,spath3}

\tikzset{
  message/.code={\message{this is message #1^^J}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
\addplot[/tikz/message=one,/tikz/spath/save global=test] coordinates {(0,0) (2,3) (5,5)};

\tikzset{message=two,spath/show=test} % path doesn't exist here

\begin{scope}
\clip (axis cs:1,1) rectangle (axis cs:4,4);
\draw[message=three,ultra thick, red,postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}][spath/use=test];
\end{scope}

\tikzset{message=four}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `message` key is included in the above to show how the order of things happens.  In the code, there are four messages in the order `one`, `two`, `three`, and `four`.  In the logfile, it produces:

```
this is message one
this is message two

Package spath3 Warning: Soft path test doesn't exist on line 17

this is message four
this is message one
this is message three
```

Note also that the `test` path doesn't exist when it is "shown" in the `\tikzset` line.  It doesn't get defined until the end of the `axis` environment.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the easiest way is just to use another `\addplot` using the same coordinate list to add the marking after having drawn the red clipped line. You could store the coordinates inside a table for easy access:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=crcr]{
0  0  \\
2  3  \\
5  5  \\
}\plotcoords

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
\addplot[save path=\test, draw=none] table {\plotcoords};

\begin{scope}
\clip (axis cs:1,1) rectangle (axis cs:4,4);
\draw[red][use path=\test];  
\end{scope}

\addplot[draw=none, postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}] table {\plotcoords};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]